# ArgumentException: Cannot create a data handler without payload data

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

After upgrading Unity Editor and Facebook SDK, Getting the following error. How to fix it

Error:

```
ArgumentException: Cannot create a data handler without payload data
UnityEngine.Networking.UploadHandlerRaw..ctor (System.Byte[] data) (at <39536a03ec01488d9573f19141ef4b8b>:0)
UnityEngine.WWW..ctor (System.String url, System.Byte[] postData, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] headers) (at <f23472e385dc4119a7eb088c22aec545>:0)
Facebook.Unity.AsyncRequestString+<Start>d__9.MoveNext () (at <1c4aa51e2fc9444383a6d6fb7ba5652f>:0)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <6a104889781c465ca00c12d0953583e2>:0)
```

Environment

> Unity Editor Version: 2021.1.0f1
>
> Facebook SDK Version: 9.2

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by legacy WWW class in Unity 2021. Upgrade to UnityWebRequest fixes the problem.

more you can read here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/537

you can just download dlls from this url and replace them in project